# Django - 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a really basic site in Django.
Right now you just have to enter your name and it gets saved.
But even though I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/)
it throws the error `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'`

My `views.py`:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import NameForm
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect


@csrf_protect
def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            with open("name.txt" , "w") as f:
                f.write(form.cleaned_data)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/nmindex/')


@csrf_protect
def vote_page(request):
    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': NameForm(request)})
```

`forms.py`:

```py
from django import forms
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

`urls.py`:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from nmindex import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('data/', views.get_name),
    path('vote/', views.vote_page),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And the template `name.html`:

```
<form action="/data/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But when I open http://localhost:8000/vote/:

```
AttributeError at /vote/

'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/vote/
Django Version:     3.0.5
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'

Exception Location:     C:\Users\Sid\Envs\namesproj\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py in value_from_datadict, line 258
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Sid\Envs\namesproj\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.8.2
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\Sid\\names',
 'C:\\Users\\Sid\\Envs\\namesproj\\Scripts\\python38.zip',
 'c:\\users\\sid\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\sid\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\sid\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32',
 'C:\\Users\\Sid\\Envs\\namesproj',
 'C:\\Users\\Sid\\Envs\\namesproj\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Sat, 2 May 2020 08:00:03 +0000
Error during template rendering

In template C:\Users\Sid\names\templates\name.html, error at line 3
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'
1   <form action="/data/" method="post">
2       {% csrf_token %}
3       {{ form }}
4       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
5   </form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with Django-forms: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728766/issue-with-django-forms-wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `vote_page` method. You can not instantiate a form with `request` as data. It expects a dictionary-like object like a `QueryDict`, for example with `request.POST` or `request.GET`, so `NameForm(request)` will not work.

```
def vote_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # …
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
>   [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
>   to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
>   This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
>   browser.

Comment: @Sid: on the code you showed, it said `return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': NameForm(request)})` (so without `.POST`). Notice that the problem happens in the `vote_page` view (as you can see in the traceback).

Comment: @Sid: where do you read in the tutorial to use `SomeForm(request)`, without `SomeForm(request.POST)`?